# Selenium Netbeans Project to runnable jar

Tags: maven, testing, selenium, netbeans, junit

I'm developing tests using junit, maven and Selenium inside Netbeans IDE. I don't have any main class inside the src folder. I can run the tests easily from the IDE, but I'm trying to pack all of them into one jar file (so I can later use with linux cron and schedule daily tests). I've searched around the web but so far my search hasn't been successful. Can anyone point me in some enlightment path please?

Comment: maybe you want to setup Jenkins (http://jenkins-ci.org/) to actually build your project including running the tests? instead of a cronjob I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class in your project that contains the main function and accepts test class names as parameter.

```
class RunTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        // Run the tests contained in the classes named in the args.
        org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(args);
    }
}
```

Now create the jar using maven including all the dependancies in pom.xml. you will be able to run tests through jar by passing test class names

for more information read [this](http://api.dpml.net/junit/4.2/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html#main%28java.lang.String...%29)